# Cloning Hard drive to smaller SSD

Tags: dd

I have a 146GB HDD in one of my servers that I want to replace with a 120GB SSD. Can I just clone the drive with `dd` and have it boot just fine?  Are there any repurcussions to cloning to a smaller drive?  (The drive is nowhere near full so there shouldn't be much at the end of the disk). The server itself only had whatever partitions Proxmox sets up when it installs.

Comment: Most cloning tools handle this just fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: @music2myear not yet because the hard drive hasn't come in yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you clone a larger drive onto a smaller drive (used space fits on the smaller)](https://superuser.com/questions/114003/can-you-clone-a-larger-drive-onto-a-smaller-drive-used-space-fits-on-the-smalle).  Additional solutions on this question (closed because it explicitly asked for product recommendations: https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to resize the current drive that you have and that way the clone can be successful. Then you can use clonezilla copy the image to an external and then copy the image to the new disk.If you are not using the space anyways the partition can be resized to match the new hard drive. Here is an example using clonezilla and gparted but you should be able to do the same thing with windows using their disk management utility.

https://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-clone-hard-drive-to-smaller-drive/

Comment: did my answer suffice?